# Is it correct ok to use ConcurrentBag<T> as object of ConcurrentDictionary<key, object>

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the following code:

```
public class SomeItem { }
public class SomeItemsBag : ConcurrentBag< SomeItem > { }
public class SomeItemsList : List< SomeItem > { }
public static class Program
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary< string, SomeItemsBag > _SomeItemsBag;
    private static ConcurrentDictionary< string, SomeItemsList > _SomeItemsList;

    private static void GetItem(string key)
    {
        var bag = _SomeItemsBag[key];
        var list= _SomeItemsList[key];
        ...
    }
}
```

My assumption is that bag is threadsafe and list is not. Is this the right way to deal with a dictionary of lists in a multithreaded app?

Edited to add:
Only 1 thread would be adding to the bag/list and another thread would remove, but many threads could access.

Comment: "right" way is a loaded term...  Bags are unordered, which may or may not be what you want, also they are optimized for performance where the same thread putting the items in is also the one taking items out.

Comment: A better question may be "I have <describe here>.  What .Net data structures would serve my concurrent needs <described here>?

Comment: So on that note, what do you want the "list" to do?  Will it be added to and removed from concurrently?  Will order matter (not saying necessarily sorted, but does the consumer expect the order of items in the list to be the same order they were put in the list)?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: the order wouldn't matter. The dictionary would contain lists of literary works, such that if the dictionary were named Works, then Works["Poems"] would contain a collection of poems. There would be multiple threads accessing and adding poems.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: strike that last part in my earlier comment to you, only 1 thread would add a poem, but many will enumerate.

Comment: Before you go too far down the `ConcurrentBag` route, you should understand its behavior. There are no guarantees about removal order. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=842 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions that the `ConcurrentBag` is thread safe and the `List` is not are correct. But, you can synchronise access to the list, for example:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary< string, SomeItemsBag > _SomeItemsBag;
private static ConcurrentDictionary< string, SomeItemsList > _SomeItemsList;
private static object _someItemsListLocker = new object();

private static void GetItem(string key)
{
    var bag = _SomeItemsBag[key];
    lock (_someItemsListLocker) {
        var list = _SomeItemsList[key];
    }
}
```

However, you're better off describing the situation completely if you want more holistic advice as to what data structure you should be using. Note that there are also `ConcurrentQueue` and `ConcurrentStack` which may be better for what you want over the list. They are optimised in multi-threaded scenarios since addition and removal can only happen on one side respectively (same sides for stack, opposite sides for queue).